# How to throw inside a stored procedure that uses a save point?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to THROW an error from a stored procedure, that uses a save point to fall back to if nested, but it is never thrown.

I searched around a bit and all I find are solutions (did not try them) that use RAISERROR, however the Microsoft documentation say's RAISERROR should not be used any longer, instead THROW should be used.

Here is some small example.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC sp_should_throw_error
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT OFF

    DECLARE @TranCounter INT;  
    SET @TranCounter = @@TRANCOUNT;  
    IF @TranCounter > 0
        SAVE TRANSACTION ProcedureSave;  
    ELSE  
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

    BEGIN TRY  
        THROW 50001, 'Spitted out an error.', 1

        IF @TranCounter = 0
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;  
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH  
        IF @TranCounter = 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
        ELSE IF XACT_STATE() <> -1 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ProcedureSave;  
    END CATCH  
END

EXEC sp_should_throw_error
```

I hope anyone can point out to me what I am doing wrong here. Why is the error never thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `THROW` in the final `CATCH` block to re-raise the error. Otherwise, it won't be raised to the client because you've caught and handled it.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC usp_should_throw_error
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT OFF

    DECLARE @TranCounter INT;  
    SET @TranCounter = @@TRANCOUNT;  
    IF @TranCounter > 0
        SAVE TRANSACTION ProcedureSave;  
    ELSE  
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

    BEGIN TRY  
        THROW 50001, 'Spitted out an error.', 1

        IF @TranCounter = 0
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;  
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH  
        IF @TranCounter = 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
        ELSE IF XACT_STATE() <> -1 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ProcedureSave;  
        THROW;
    END CATCH  
END;
GO
```

Comment: @Mili, could you give an example of how to use an OUT param for that?

Comment: @Mili, for what reason is an output parameter better? The calling code can catch and handle a raised error as desired. The error message, severity, state, etc. is available with structured error handling.

Comment: Yes it,s easy to handle